# Value error : [ValueError: labels ['Link'] not contained in axis]

Tags: python

I m getting Value error when i try to drop few columns from the dataframe.

```
--> df.columns --
Index(['Name of School', 'Elementary, Middle, or High School',
       'Street Address', 'ZIP Code', 'Link ', 'Healthy Schools Certified?']

--> df.drop('Link', axis=1)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: labels ['Link'] not contained in axis
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
df.drop('Link ', axis=1)
```

The column name is `'link '`. It has a space in the end